# How to use a Google Font once it is installed on your machine

Tags: html, css, fonts, google-font-api

So I know this is a very newbie question but I cant seem to figure this out, don't know what I am doing wrong here. Downloaded a font from Google Fonts, installed it on my machine and am referencing it in my css like this:

```
* { margin:0; padding:0; font-family:Lobster; }
```

In my html I just have a p tag:

```
<p> Hi, this is some text</p>
```

Are there any extra steps that need to be taken to use a google font installed on your local machine ??

Comment: A tipp: never add the `font-family` on the asterisk `*`. That will slow down the browsers CSS rendering imense as he needs to check every single element in your DOM. Add it to the `<body>` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct syntax to use a font is `font-family:'Lobster', Arial;`
Here if the Lobster font is not available it will use the Arial.

Also you can just import a font file in the css.

CSS

```
@import url(//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster:400);
body{ font-family:'Lobster', Arial; }
```

[DEMO](http://fiddle.jshell.net/58Lea/1/)

Comment: Seems like the quotation marks around the font did the trick, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to download google fonts on your machine to add in your web pages.

Add the following link between your ead tags

```
<link  rel="stylesheet" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=lobster">
```

Answer (score 0):

There are no extra steps that you need to take *if* you have actually not just downloaded the font but also installed it (so that you can see it e.g. in the font menu of Notepad) *and* you just want to see that font used when you *locally* view your own pages.

If you want to use it on web pages, you should generate the relevant font files in different formats, upload them onto your server, and use `@font-face` syntax that deals with them.